# Display notification to alert app user once temperature abnormal (over the limit)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-notifications

I need display notifications when Firebase database return specific values which has exceed the limits. This is for alert the android user for abnormal condition. I am running raspberry pi 3 and taskschedule running every time sending data to firebase database, once the database return overlimit value, i need display message through notification, (display icon and notification on display). I had conducted the tutorial from the Android forum but it seems problem happen where everytime the data are updated, the notification is automatically alert. (no matters in abnormal or normal condition). Can u do me a favor? I upload real-time database as well as the android layout in here [real time database and android layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVOU.png)

This is my java class code:(I juz put air temperature example seems other parameter i used the same method to do it)

```
public class RealtimeData extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatebase;
private DatabaseReference mDatebase2;
private DatabaseReference mDatebase3;
private DatabaseReference mDatebase4;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase5;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase6;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase7;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase8;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase9;

private TextView mTempView;
private TextView mHumidView;
private TextView mTimeView;
private TextView mphView;
private TextView mwaterView;
private TextView mCO2View;
//private TextView mTVOCView;
private TextView mTDSView;
private TextView mDateView;
private TextView mWaterTempView;


WifiManager wifiManager;
TextView wifiStatusTextView;

Switch wifiSwitch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    buildDialog(RealtimeData.this).show();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_realtime_data);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Toast.makeText(RealtimeData.this,"Make sure device is connected to The internet for latest data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiStatusTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_status);
    wifiSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.wifiswitch);

    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: ON");
        wifiSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: OFF");
        wifiSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }

    wifiSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: ON");
                Toast.makeText(RealtimeData.this,"WIFI may take a moment to turn on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: OFF");
            }
        }
    });




    mDatebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading");
    mTempView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempvalue);

    mDatebase.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot datasnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String temp = datasnap.child("airtemperature").getValue(String.class);
                if (Float.valueOf(temp) >= 24 && Float.valueOf(temp) <= 30) {
                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Normal");
                }
                else if (Float.valueOf(temp) < 24)
                {

                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal Low");
                    finalBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.impressive);
                    finalBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
                    finalBuilder.setContentText("Air Temperature is abnormally Low!!!");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, finalBuilder.build());

                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal Low ");
                }

                else if (Float.valueOf(temp) > 30)
                {

                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal High ");
                    finalBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.impressive);
                    finalBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
                    finalBuilder.setContentText("Air Temperature is abnormally High!!!");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, finalBuilder.build());

                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal High ");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: Error");

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: the notification is appear once the database renew the value(temp value),  I want to make sure that the notification  only alert once it is abnormal.

Comment: the error is that eventhough  it is in normal condition (24 < temp < 30), the notification  is alerted, i have no idea on what had happened